# Creating a for loop with results based on another table

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop

I have two lists of objects, buildnumbers and partrequestnumbers.
Both list contain buildnumbers, and what I am trying to achieve is a html list of the buildnumbers with their associated parturequestnumbers, the link being the buildnumber. So far I have had a look at numpy arrays and a few for loop suggestions without achieving what I am trying to achieve. My current for loop just loops through all of the numbers...
[The image shows the build list, I'd like the partnumbers next to it too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMvFY.png)
Django Views:

```
def manufacturelist(request, mug=None, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404 
    partrequests = PartRequestNumbers.objects.order_by('-id')
    latest_preparebuild_list = PrepareBuild.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    builds=[]
    for preparebuild in latest_preparebuild_list:
        bb = preparebuild.buildno
        builds.append(PartRequestNumbers.objects.filter(buildno=bb))
    context = {
        "latest_preparebuild_list": latest_preparebuild_list,
        "partrequests": partrequests,
        "builds": builds,
    }
    return render(request, "buildpage/manufacturelist.html", context)
```

HTML:

```
 {% if latest_preparebuild_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for preparebuild in latest_preparebuild_list %}

       <li><a class = "subtitle" >{{ preparebuild.buildno }}: </a><a style= "float: right" href="/buildpage/{{ preparebuild.part_request }}/manufacturebuild">{{ partrequests.part_request }}</a><p style= "float: right">{{ preparebuild.build_status }}</p></li>
      {% for partrequest in partrequests %} 
      <center><a href="/buildpage/{{ partrequest.part_request }}/manufacturebuild">{{ partrequest.part_request }}&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></center>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No builds are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

models:

```
class PrepareBuild(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default= datetime.now)
    STATUS = Choices('Complete', 'In-Build', 'Awaiting Build', 'Cancelled', 'Design Issue', 'M/C Issue')
    buildstatus = StatusField()
    status_changed = MonitorField(monitor='buildstatus')
    buildno = models.CharField(_('Build Number'),max_length=10, default= bnumber)
    current_location = models.ForeignKey(BuildLocation, default='', null=True)
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, max_length=10, default ="")
    batchno = models.CharField(_('Batch Number'),max_length=100, default="")
    partnumber = models.CharField(_('Part Number(s)'), max_length = 100, default = 'e.g. 002109_1')
    buildtime = models.CharField(_('Build Time'), default= '', max_length=100)
    buildnotes = models.CharField(_('Build Notes'), max_length=200, default = "", blank=True)
    mug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.buildno or default
class PartRequestNumbers(models.Model):
    buildno = models.CharField(_('Build Number'),max_length=10, default= bnumber)   
    part_request = models.ForeignKey(PartRequest, related_name='PR Number+', null=True) 
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}' .format(self.part_request)
```

Comment: I think you need to show us an example of what the desired output is, as well as the models.

Comment: updated accordingly

Comment: the view does what I want it to do, the html doesn't